# Are there common ways or standards for frameserving?

Tags: c++, video, video-streaming, video-processing

Posting [this](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/21896/is-there-standard-protocol-or-way-for-frameserving) question from video.SE here for being about programming.

My program produces sequence of frames (frameserver) of an on-screen animation, then some video-processing program (likely, ffmpeg) overlays them on another video to continuously save the result on disk or send to youtube-like service.

So, are there any standard practices I can implement in my program-frameserver so that most video-processing software could pick up the stream? How-to would be appreciated.

The intended workflow:

[my program in C++] -> frames (up to 60fps 1080p) -> [consumer (videoprocessing program)] ->...

Thanks for help!

Comment: Depends entirely on what you're doing with it.  Raw frames are about as elementary as it gets, but there is no standard without context.

Comment: @Brad, as I described, my program produces sequence of frames (on-screen animation), then some video-processing program (likely, ffmpeg) overlays them on another video to continuously save the result on disk or send to youtube. Was the explanation useful?

Comment: You should add those details to your question.  If you're starting with animation and then using FFmpeg, I'd stick with raw frames, RGB24 or similar.

Comment: @Brad so how would video-processors usually expect the video stream? On std in? Seems simple and reliable.

Comment: Yes, FFmpeg takes STDIN.  For the input file, just specify `-`.

Comment: @Brad It works, but now the image in ffplay is a little distorted in the middle, there're some slightly visible colourful lines and the whole picture cyclically floats right for some reason (on each new frame), though it is well-recognizable and the source image is proper... Don't you happen to know the reason?) The command is `my_prog.exe | .\ffplay.exe -f rawvideo -s 1280x720 -pix_fmt rgb24 -i pipe:0`. Saving file using fmpeg instead of ffplay gives same artefacts in the picture.

Comment: Sounds like your pixel count is wrong on some dimension.